# Angular Modal Service does not clean up after itself

Tags: angularjs

I'm using the [Angular Modal Service](https://github.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service#faq) to display a modal.  In my case the modal is not cleaning up after itself.  Meaning when you run the modal, the modal HTML stays in the DOM.    I've seen examples where this does not happen, why is it happening in my example?

Here is a fiddle with the example:  http://jsfiddle.net/Ljo6ct4e/1/

This is my JS:

**Javascript**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['angularModalService']);

app.controller('Controller', function($scope, ModalService) {

    $scope.show = function() {
        ModalService.showModal({
            template: "<div class='modal fade'>" + 
            "   <div class='modal-dialog'>" +
            "      <div class='modal-content'>" +
            "         <button type='button' ng-click=" + "close('close')" +  "class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>" +
            "         <div class='modal-body'><p >this is a modal</p></div>" +
            "      </div>" + 
            "   </div>" + 
            "</div>",
            controller: "ModalController",
            controllerAs : "modal"
        }).then(function(modal) {
            modal.element.modal();
            modal.close.then(function(result) {
                $scope.message = "You said " + result;
            });
        });
    };

});

app.controller('ModalController', function($scope, close) {
 $scope.close = function(result) {
    close(result, 500); // close, but give 500ms for bootstrap to animate
 };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your scope function should not have the same name as the service. Rename it `$scope.closeModal`. Then use that in ng-click (you have syntax errors in your button html too). Then use the bootstrap function to hide the modal and call the close service with null as result.

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ljo6ct4e/2/